# Delete redundant entries within groups

Tags: postgresql, pandas, group-by, duplicates

I want to remove redundant rows in my database within each group (in this case datasource), which I define as rows which contains strictly less information or different information than some other row.

For example in the table below. Row 1 is redundant as the other row row 0 in its same group contains the exact same information as it but with more data.

For the same reason row 6 is redundant all the other rows 3, 4 and 5 in the group contains more information that it. However I keep both row 4 and 5 as they have some additional different information than the other rows in the group.

```
   datasource         city country
0           1    Shallotte      US
1           1         None      US
2           2       austin      US
3           3  Casselberry      US
4           3         None      AU
5           3  Springfield    None
6           3         None    None
```

An example when there are more columns, rows 0 and 1, 4 are different information. However rows 2 and 3(or row 1) contains redundant information.

```
  datasource         city country   Count
0           1        None       US     11
1           1       austin    None   None
2           1        None     None     11
3           1       austin    None   None
4           1        None       CA   None
```

Expected output

```
  datasource         city country   Count
0           1        None       US     11
1           1       austin    None   None
4           1        None       CA   None
```

Is there a simple way which I could achieve such logic in pandas or SQL (PostrgeSQL) for any number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach using the same basic strategy as Bharath shetty's solution.  This way feels a bit neater to me.

First, construct the example data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"datasource": [1,1,2,3,3,3,3],
        "city": ["Shallotte", None, "austin", "Casselberry", None, "Springfield", None],
        "country": ["US", "US", "US", "US", "AU", None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['null'] = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)

print(df)
          city country  datasource  null
0    Shallotte      US           1     0
1         None      US           1     1
2       austin      US           2     0
3  Casselberry      US           3     0
4         None      AU           3     1
5  Springfield    None           3     1
6         None    None           3     2
```

Now make a boolean mask using `groupby` and `apply` - we just drop the biggest null values per group:

```
def null_filter(d):
    if len(d) > 1:
        return d.null < d.null.max()
    return d.null == d.null

mask = df.groupby("datasource").apply(null_filter).values

df.loc(mask).drop("null", 1)
```

Output:

```
             city country  datasource
0    Shallotte      US           1
2       austin      US           2
3  Casselberry      US           3
4         None      AU           3
5  Springfield    None           3
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is based on None Count and removing rows of maximum None values i.e

```
#Count the None values across the row
df['Null'] = (df.values == 'None').sum(axis=1)

#Get the maximum of the count based on groupby
df['Max'] = df.groupby('datasource')['Null'].transform(max)

# Get the values are not equal to max and  equal to zero and drop the columns
df = df[~((df['Max'] !=0) & (df['Max'] == df['Null']))].drop(['Null','Max'],axis=1)
```

Output :

```
  datasource         city country
0           1    Shallotte      US
2           2       austin      US
3           3  Casselberry      US
4           3         None      AU
5           3  Springfield    None
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, however this does not work when there are more columns, i've given an example, sorry if my question wasn't clear at first

Comment: Sir your idea of redundant data is bit hard to understand. Can you add the expected output you want.